# Book Store Inventory Array Book Name Sorting Issue

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, inventory

I usually try to research and learn but I have hit a wall.
By School assignment has us building an array to hold book store information and then wanting us to sort it by book name.

I'm not sure if I did the array right and I could really use some tips on sorting this array.

//////////////////////////////////////Code so far

///Book store class

```
import java.util.Arrays;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class BookStore {//BookStore class
public static void main(String args[]) {
```

//Array

```
Book[] Books = new Book[5];

Books[0] = new Book(9780007525492L,"B book","J. R. R. Tolkien",2013,"Harper Collins", 5.00);
Books[1] = new Book(9780007525492L,"D book","J. R. R. Tolkien",2013,"Harper Collins", 5.00);
Books[2] = new EBook(9780007525492L,"C book","J. R. R. Tolkien",2013,"Harper Collins", 5.00,"www.amazon.com");
Books[3] = new Book(9780007525492L,"A book","J. R. R. Tolkien",2013,"Harper Collins", 5.00);
Books[4] = new EBook(9780007525492L,"E book","J. R. R. Tolkien",2013,"Harper Collins", 5.00,"www.amazon.com");
```

//Sorting

//Output

```
    System.out.print("Bookstore Items:\n");

for (int counter=0;counter<Books.length;counter++){
    System.out.println(Books[counter]);

}
```

//Total Inventory value

```
double total = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){ 
    total +=  Books[i].getPrice();            
}
System.out.printf("\nTotal Inventory Value: $%.2f\n", total);   

}
}
```

//Book class

```
class Book{


private long isbnNumber; //ISBN
private String bookName;//Title 
private String authName;//Author
private int pubYear; //year published
private String pubName;//Publishers name
private double price; //Price
```

//Constructor for Book

```
Book(long number, String bname, String aname, int year, String pname, double cost)
{ 
isbnNumber = number; 
bookName = bname; 
authName = aname;
pubName = pname;
pubYear = year;
price = cost;

}
```

//getisbnNumber: gets isbn

```
public long getIsbnNumber() 
{ 
    return isbnNumber; 
}
```

//setisbnNumber: sets isbn

```
public void setIsbnNumber(long number) 
{ 

}
```

//getbookName: gets book name

```
public String getBookName() 
{ 
    return bookName; 
}
```

//setbookName: sets book name

```
public void setBookName(String bname) 
{ 

}
```

//getauthName: gets author name

```
public String getAuthName() 
{ 
    return authName; 
}
```

//setAuthName: sets the author name

```
public void setAuthName(String aname) 
{ 

}
```

//getpubName: gets publisher name

```
public String getpubName() 
{ 
    return pubName; 
}
```

//setpubName: sets the publisher name

```
public void setPubName(String pname) 
{ 

}
```

//getPrice: returns the price for the book

```
public double getPrice() 
{ 
    return price; 
}
```

//setPrice: sets the price for the book

```
public void setPrice(int cost) 
{ 

}
```

//getpubYear: gets published year

```
public int getPubYear() 
{ 
    return pubYear; 
}
```

//setpubYear: sets published year

```
public void setPubYear(int year) 
{ 

}
```

//Printout of the individual item for display

```
public String toString(){ 
    return String.format("\n\n%s\t%s\n%s\t\t%s\n%s\t\t%s\n%s\t\t%d\n%s\t%s\n%s\t\t$%,.2f  ","ISBN:\t", getIsbnNumber(), 
            "Title:", getBookName(), "Author:", getAuthName(),"Year:", getPubYear(), "Publisher:", getAuthName(), "Price:", getPrice()); 


}
}
```

//EBook Sub Class

```
class EBook extends Book{

private String webSite;//web url
private String getWebSite() {
    return webSite;
}


private double getDiscount() {
    return discount;
}

private double discount;


//EBook constructor

EBook(long number, String bname, String aname, int year, String pname,
        double cost, String web) {super(number, bname, aname, year, pname, cost);
        discount = cost*.10;
        webSite = web;      
}

public String toString(){ 
            return

String.format("\n\n%s\t%s\n%s\t\t%s\n%s\t\t%s\n%s\t\t%d\n%s\t%s\n%s\t\t$%,.2f\n%s\t%s\n%s\t$%,.2f    ","ISBN:\t", getIsbnNumber(),"Title:", getBookName(), "Author:", getAuthName(),"Year:",   getPubYear(), "Publisher:", getAuthName(), "Price:", getPrice(),   "Website:",getWebSite(),"Discount:", getDiscount()); 

}

}
```

///////////////////////////////////// program output

---

Bookstore Items:

ISBN:       9780007525492

Title:      B book

Author:     J. R. R. Tolkien

Year:       2013

Publisher:  J. R. R. Tolkien

Price:      $5.00

ISBN:       9780007525492

Title:      D book

Author:     J. R. R. Tolkien

Year:       2013

Publisher:  J. R. R. Tolkien

Price:      $5.00

ISBN:       9780007525492

Title:      C book

Author:     J. R. R. Tolkien

Year:       2013

Publisher:  J. R. R. Tolkien

Price:      $5.00

Website:    www.amazon.com

Discount:   $0.50

ISBN:       9780007525492

Title:      A book

Author:     J. R. R. Tolkien

Year:       2013

Publisher:  J. R. R. Tolkien

Price:      $5.00

ISBN:       9780007525492

Title:      E book

Author:     J. R. R. Tolkien

Year:       2013

Publisher:  J. R. R. Tolkien

Price:      $5.00

Website:    www.amazon.com

Discount:   $0.50

Total Inventory Value: $25.00

Comment: Where is your code that sorts and what issue you are acing in that, post those details.

Comment: For sorting, you should have a look at the [sort method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator)) of the Arrays class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I sort custom objects alphabetically in an array in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21225775/how-do-i-sort-custom-objects-alphabetically-in-an-array-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the sorting like this:

1) Implement the [`Comaparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface in your `Book` class:

```
   public class Book implements Comparable<Book>{

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Book book) {
        return this.bookName.compareTo(book.bookName);
    }
   }
```

2) Then do the sorting using [Arrays.sort(obect[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object[]%29) method:

```
   // Sorting
    Arrays.sort(Books); // Add this line

    for (int counter = 0; counter < Books.length; counter++) {
        System.out.println(Books[counter]);

    }
```

If you want to sort on different properties of `Book` class then you can use [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), for example:

```
    // Sorting based on Author name
    Arrays.sort(Books, new Comparator<Book>() {
        public int compare(Book book1, Book book2) {
            return book1.getAuthName().compareTo(book2.getAuthName());
        }
    });

    // Sorting based on ISBN
    Arrays.sort(Books, new Comparator<Book>() {
        public int compare(Book book1, Book book2) {
            return new Long(book1.getIsbnNumber()).compareTo(book2.getIsbnNumber());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array looks just fine. Nothing wrong about it.

Sorting an array isn't that hard. Googling a second would have provided an answer.
As you can see [here](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/arrays/70sorting.html), sorting works with numbers and characters.
So in your case it would look something like this:

```
Books.sort(bookName);
```

I hope this solved your issue.

Comment: Thanks to all that answer I really thank full for you effort. but i just figured it out on my own. I was frustrated went outside to feed the dogs, cleared my head and tried again. so it works now. but thanks allot.

Comment: that's great. But could you mark the correct answer anyway, or tell us how you did it?